# Bash scripts - Why isn't echo executing?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I have tried to make a bash script.

```
vi hello_world
```

Inside the script i have written

```
#!/bin/bash
text="Hello World"
echo $text
```

When i type in

```
echo $hello_world
```

Shouldn't the script be run then i print out "Hello World" ? Or is something wrong in the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the wrong syntax to call the script.

```sh
echo $hello_world
```

prints the contents of the variable `hello_world`.

You need to type the path to the script to execute the shell script `hello_world`:

```sh
./hello_world
```

This executes `hello_world` if it is in the current working directory.

To run the script directly (ie with `./script`), you need to make the it executable. You can do this with:

```sh
chmod +x ./hello_world
```

or by using the file properties dialog of your file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the script is in your current working directory, you will need to run the following to execute your script.

```
./hello_world
```

If you script doesn't already have permissions to execute, you can do so with `chmod +x hello_world`

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the location of `bash` is different.

You could use the bootstrap instead

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
text="Hello World"
echo $text
```

EDIT: It was so obvious, that I didn't seen the wrong syntax to run the script. Try:

```
./hello_world
```